# Find System Hard Disk Drive from Python?

Tags: python, winapi, system, disk

I am working on a software installer for my current application. It needs to be installed to the System HDD. How owuld I detect the system drive and return the letter from Python?

Would the win32 extensions be useful? How about the os module pre packaged with Python?

Comment: *"It needs to be installed to the System HDD."* - If your application requires to be stored in a particular location you should probably fix the issue in your application responsible for this requirement.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This is how to return the letter of the System drive on a Win32 platform:**

```
import os
print os.getenv("SystemDrive")
```

The above snippet returns the system drive letter. In my case ( and most cases on windows) C:

Comment: Note: this works only on NT platforms. Windows 9x didn't have this environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the win32 extensions, the following will get you the information you want:

```
In [82]: import win32api

In [83]: drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()

In [84]: drives
Out[84]: 'C:\\\x00D:\\\x00E:\\\x00'

In [85]: drives.split('\x00')
Out[85]: ['C:\\', 'D:\\', 'E:\\', '']
```

Ignore the last item, due to a terminating character in the string returned by win32's [GetLogicalDriveStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but that isn't what I need. That method returns every drive that is connected to the system. I just need the drive the OS is installed on. I figured out how to do and answered it below.

Comment: Ah, got it.  You should just go ahead and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32api #https://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api.html
print("GetWindowsDirectory:", win32api.GetWindowsDirectory()[0])
#or
print("GetSystemDirectory:", win32api.GetSystemDirectory())
```

Output:

> GetWindowsDirectory: C
>
> GetSystemDirectory: C:\Windows\system32