# Search all drives for a file

Tags: python, windows, file, path

I have the name of a file and I want to find it on whatever Drive it is. I can use a recursive search, but I need a root directory to start with. For most computers, the root is "C:\". But there are some that have changed the letter, or some that have more than one (eg. C,D...).

So, I need to find a way to know all the Drives in a computer, so I can search through each one. I need to find the letters programmatically without user input.

I know I can use "diskpart", but it requires an administrator access, something my code will not have. There is also "wmic", but I don't know if the computer has the right folder in the PATH.

So, the question is how can I do a recursive search in a computer which I don't know the letters of the drives or how many are there? Or is there another way to find the path of a file in a computer?

Comment: You could use `os.path.abspath('blank')` to figure out the current drive, it would return a path like `C:/Python27/blank`. But are you trying to determine what multiple drives are?

Comment: Hi tamird14, I see that you have a good idea (recursive search), so I dare say your problem is finding the letter of the HD. I suggest you change the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006740/4374739) helps if you have win32api installed

Comment: And using for example: `os.getcwd` can give you access to the letter of the current drive.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan my goal is to find the path of the file.

Comment: @Jblasco not strictly a duplicate because that question wants something other than OP, and OP only wants it as part of a bigger question.

Comment: @tamird14 Can you assume anything about which drive it will be on? ie. the same drive as the script maybe?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan No, and that is the problem. That is why i want to find all the letters, so that i can use recursive search on each one

Comment: @Clodion The file is not necessary in the current drive

Comment: @Jblasco My main goal is to find the path of a file (so i can later do stuff with it). If someone has another way to do it, it might be better than recursive search

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, as I see it, strictly speaking, the OP is asking two questions, both of which are in several places in stackoverflow, meaning "Is there a way to list all the available drive letters in python?" and "find a file in python".

Comment: @Jblasco That is the case broadly speaking, but I couldn't find a way to do it without having to use admin permissions (as I hackily managed to do in my answer) so I feel like it is a different situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution that requires you run as an administrator, but does not require you install any other tools. I then have an alternative, messy solution that you can run even without any of these privileges. I'll start with the cleaner one.

This script will find you the drives:

```
import subprocess

driveStr = subprocess.check_output("fsutil fsinfo drives")
driveStr = driveStr.strip().lstrip('Drives: ')
drives = driveStr.split()
```

Basically, `fsutil fsinfo drives` is a commandline command that will return the letters of existing drives on your computer. So you can get that result with `check_output` and then strip away the unnecessary characters, because it will return a string like `'\r\nDrives: C:\\ D:\\ \r\n'`. Then you can split the list and you'll have a list of drives like this:

```
['C:\\', 'D:\\']
```

You can then loop over those drives to recursively search for a file.

```
import os

def find_file(target, folder):
    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, f)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            result = find_file(target, path)
            if result is not None:
                return result
            continue
        if f == target:
            return path
```

This function will basically loop over every file in the folder it's provided, it first checks if the file is a folder with `isdir`, and runs recursively on any folders it finds. If it's not a folder, it will check for the file named `target` and return its path when found. You can combine these two parts pretty simply:

```
for drive in drives:
    filepath = find_file(target, drive)
    if filepath is not None:
        break
```

However, if you're unable to run as administrator, there is another way that's not as nice. Basically you could just loop over all the possible drive names and check if they exist, like this:

```
drives = ['{}:\\' for letter in 'CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
for drive in drives:
    if os.path.isdir(drive):
        filepath = find_file(target, drive)
        if filepath is not None:
            break
```

This will check if each drive exists as a directory and search each one that does. Note this will include networked paths and I believe USBs/external hard drives, while the alternative method does not.

Comment: If the code doesn't run as an administrator, what can I do?

Comment: @tamird14 Windows makes this hard with User Account Control (UAC), and I'm not that familiar with it so I'm not sure how to work around it. There's a method that involves installing Python's `win32api` if you want to go that route.

Comment: @tamird14 I came up with a less than ideal way to test if the directories exist, check out the last part of my edited answer.

Comment: There's no reason to require admin access just to get the user's logical drives. Just use ctypes to call [`GetLogicalDrives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972), which returns the drive bitmask. For example: `import ctypes;` `dmask = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives();` `drives = [chr(ord('A') + n) for n in range(26) if (dmask >> n) & 1]`.

Comment: Also, use `os.walk` to walk over the files on each drive. In Python 3.5 [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) is reimplemented to use the new `os.scandir` function, which makes it many times faster on Windows.

Comment: In newer versions of Python, you have to use `drives = [f'{letter}:\\' for letter in 'CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']`.

Answer (score -3):

If I'm understanding correctly you know the name of the file.

Using `os.path.abspath('myfile.txt')` should return the full path.

Afterwards you can use the `os.path.dirname` to get only the directory.

According to documentation os.path should be cross-platform: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path but I haven't tried it on Windows.

Comment: No, the OP wants to recursively search in every folder of a given hard drive for the file.