# How to print the partition name, in which Windows is installed?

Tags: python

Can anybody tell me how to print the partition name, in which Windows is installed? For example on my PC, Windows is installed in 'c:\' partition and I want a script that can print that partition/storage name as 'c:\' (On my PC). Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006730/find-system-hard-disk-drive-from-python

Answer (score 2):

use `os.environ`

```
import os
print os.environ.get('windir')
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `SystemDrive` holds this information.

In a command prompt:

```
echo %SystemDrive%
```

In python, you could use

```
import os
print (os.environ.get('SystemDrive'))
```

See the output of the `set` command in a command prompt for more useful variables.